# Implementing infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to use infinite scroll but nothing is happening at all when I scroll down. This is how my current pagination looks:

```
<ul class="elgg-pagination">
   <li class="elgg-state-disabled"><span>« Previous</span></li>
   <li class="elgg-state-selected"><span>1</span></li>
   <li><a href="http://siteexample.com/casting?offset=10">2</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://siteexample.com/casting?offset=20">3</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://siteexample.com/casting?offset=30">4</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://siteexample.com/casting?offset=40">5</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://siteexample.com/casting?offset=50">6</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://siteexample.com/casting?offset=10">Next »</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is how my javascript looks:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var mostOfTheWayDown = ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 9 / 10;   
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= mostOfTheWayDown){
$container.infinitescroll({

  navSelector  : $('a',find('.elgg-state-selected')),    // selector for the paged     navigation 
  nextSelector : $('a',find('.elgg-state-selected').next('li').not('.elgg-state-disabled')),  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
  itemSelector : '.item1',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
  loading: {
  finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
  img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
}
  },
  // trigger Masonry as a callback
  function( newElements ) {
    // hide new items while they are loading
    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
    // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
      // show elems now they're ready
      $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
      $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
     });
  }
);
  }
```

Comment: Did you open the console and check for errors

Comment: TypeError: find(...).next is not a function

Comment: Then you know what the problem is, there is no find inside a selector like that.

Comment: How should i approach on getting the navSelector and nextselector values?  I'm still kinda confused on that

Comment: How about `$('.elgg-state-selected').find('a');`

Comment: i changed it to this:  navSelector  : $('.elgg-state-selected').find('a'),    // selector for the paged navigation 
  nextSelector :$('.elgg-state-selected').next('li').not('.elgg-state-disabled').find('a'),       still doesnt work

Comment: the error went away though but still doesnt do/see anything

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend this plugin , dont waste your time reinventing the wheel , enjoy the awesomeness of jQuery !

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

```
// infinitescroll() is called on the element that surrounds 
// the items you will be loading more of
  $('#content').infinitescroll({

    navSelector  : "div.navigation",            
                   // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
    nextSelector : "div.navigation a:first",    
                   // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : "#content div.post"          
                   // selector for all items you'll retrieve
  });
```

you may also try this :

http://airbnb.github.io/infinity/demo-on.html